# Why am I getting ArgumentError when calling Rails tag helper with a nil argument?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use Rails tag helper to create a list item in one of my views but I get `ArgumentError` when calling `tag.li` with a `nil` argument.

The portion of code where the error arises looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <%= tag.li('Some text', logged_in? ? {class: 'active'} : nil) %>
</ul>
```

And the error message says:
`wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2)`

The problem only appears when `logged_in?` returns `false` and `nil` is passed as an argument. I tried with the following code and was able to get the same error:

```
<ul>
  <%= tag.li('Some text', nil) %>
</ul>
```

If the second argument of `tag.li` is optional, why am I getting that error?

Of course I could simply do `<%= tag.li('Some text', logged_in? ? {class: 'active'} : {}) %>` but not knowing the reason behind that error is really bugging me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens is that rails is seeing that as a call to [`tag_string`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-1-stable/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb#L44) as:

```
<%= tag.tag_string('li', 'Some Text', nil) %>
```

which uses the double splat `**` operator to convert the last parameter into a hash. So what happens if you don't pass a hash?

```
def double_splat_test(**args)
  puts args.inspect
end

double_splat_test(nil)
# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

this happens for any non-hash value you pass:

```
double_splat_test('not a hash')
# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

but works nicely with hashes:

```
double_splat_test(something: 'goes here')
# {:something=>"goes here"}
```

So **wrong number of arguments** is just the error ruby chooses to give when you mess up with the `**` operator and don't give it a hash. Initially, it's a bit of a confusing error to be sure, but thinking about it a little, IMO, it makes sense. That's all that's happening here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `tag.li` is expecting a hash as an argument.  See if you get an error if you change your code to:

```
<ul>
  <%= tag.li('Some text', logged_in? ? {class: 'active'} : {) %>
</ul>
```

Comment: I assume you meant

    <%= tag.li('Some text', logged_in? ? {class: 'active'} : {}) %>

Yes, I tried that and it worked fine. However, that doesn't explain why Rails is telling me I tried to pass 3 arguments.